# how to read (or parse) google spreadsheet colums note(comment) using python

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets-api

I've a Google Spreadsheet and there is a two column

```
id , name
1     aaaa
```

and  there a note for Colum **name** and row 1 that means in the cell(2,2)
I am able to read data for tow column of the spreadsheet but could not read the note of that cell.
I am using **gspread** library for reading data from the spreadsheet.

```
import gspread
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
            'jasonfileNlocation.json',
            scope)
google_spreadsheet_connection = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = google_spreadsheet_connection.open("spreadsheet_name")
worksheet = wks.get_worksheet(0)
df = get_as_dataframe(worksheet, evaluate_formulas=True, index='false')
```

for better understanding i have added below image
[image]
Any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve notes of the cells on the Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using the Service account and Python.
- In your script, `ServiceAccountCredentials` is used as `from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials`.
- You have already been able to put and get values for Spreadsheet using Sheets API with gspread.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Unfortunately, it seems that the notes cannot be retrieved by gspread. So how about using [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)? In this answer, the notes of the cells are retrieved using the method of spreadsheets.get in Sheets API with google-api-python-client.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your script was modified.

```
import gspread
import httplib2
from apiclient import discovery
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
            'jasonfileNlocation.json',
            scope)
google_spreadsheet_connection = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = google_spreadsheet_connection.open("spreadsheet_name")
worksheet = wks.get_worksheet(0)
df = get_as_dataframe(worksheet, evaluate_formulas=True, index='false')

# I added below script.
service = discovery.build(
    'sheets', 'v4', http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

spreadsheet_id = '###'  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID here.
ranges = ['Sheet1!A2:B']  # For example, when you want to retrieve the note from the cells "A2:B" of "Sheet1", please use this.

fields = 'sheets(data(rowData(values(note,userEnteredValue))))'
request = service.spreadsheets().get(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=ranges, fields=fields)
response = request.execute()
print(response)
```

- I could understand that `ID` is the value of the column "A", and you want to the values of `EMPID` and `name together with the notes.

#### Result:

```
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {"userEnteredValue": {"numberValue": 1}},
                {"note": "sample note1", "userEnteredValue": {"stringValue": "name1"}}
              ]
            },
            {
              "values": [
                {"userEnteredValue": {"numberValue": 2}},
                {"note": "sample note2", "userEnteredValue": {"stringValue": "name2"}}
              ]
            },
            ,
            ,
            ,

          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

- The index of `rowData` is the row number.
- The index of `values` is the column number.

#### Note:

- In this sample, the note of the cell "B2" in the sheet of "Sheet1" is retrieved. If you want to retrieve other cells, please modify this.
- In this modified script, gspread can be also used.

#### References:

- [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)
- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I want to read this note with others value not just the note because in that case i will lose the track of note from which id this note is coming

Comment: @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide more information? 1. Can you explain about `others value` of `I want to read this note with others value not just the note`? 2. Can you explain about `id` of `the track of note from which id this note is coming`?

Comment: "he is late" for id 1 but in the JSON value that I got there is no track this is for id 1

Comment: @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin Thank you for replying. I could understand that `ID` is the value of the column "A", and you want to the values of `EMPID` and `name` together with the notes. By this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? I modified `fields` and `ranges`. And also I put the returned object.